# Hibernate delete objects on cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, cascading-deletes

I'm sligthly confused as to how the cascade="delete" works. I defined the mapping in the following way in the City mapping file:

```
<set inverse="true" name="client" cascade="delete">
  <key>
    <column name="id_name"/>
  </key>
    <one-to-many class="model.Client"/>
 </set>
```

The class Client has a foreign key to a class City.

So when I run:

```
List object = null;
try {
   org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
   try {
       session.delete("from City where row_id=" + row_id and table_id = " + table_id);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Should all the clients be deleted as well or do I have to handle it somehow? Am I passing the query as a method parameter correctly to the delete() method of a session? Thanks for any help.
Best Regards,
sass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm slightly confused as to how the cascade="delete" works (...)

Cascading a `delete` operation means that if you `delete` a parent, the operation will be propagated along the association. So in your case, deleting a `City` entity should be propagated to the `Client`s.

> So when I run (...) Should all the clients be deleted as well

The `Session#delete(String)` method that takes a **HQL query string**, executes it, iterates over the results and calls `Session#delete(Object)` on each object respect cascading (so the Clients will be deleted if your query is really a HQL query).

But this method is old and has been deprecated in Hibernate 3 (and moved to the "classic" `Session` interface), I do not really recommend it (it performs 1+N operations and is pretty inefficient to delete a huge number of results).

If this is a concern, prefer the **bulk delete** support offered by Hibernate:

```
int deleteCount = session.createQuery("delete from Foo where bar = :bar") 
    .setParameter("bar", bar);
    .executeUpdate()
```

But note that bulk delete has restrictions:

- You can not use aliases.
- No inner joins in the query (although you can use subselects in the where clause).
- A **bulk delete does not cascade** (and won't take care of join tables).

So with a bulk delete, you'd have to delete the `Client` before the `City`. But performances are much better.

PS: You need to `commit()` at some point (and also improve your error handling i.e. `rollback()` in the catch block)

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [14.4. DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct)

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I prefer to use the cascade delete since it handles a good part of the code. The code that i presented in the original post is just a part of the code, so there is error handling and commit.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you delete a city, then all clients will be deleted as well. If you delete a client, the city will be left alone.
2. `session.delete()` can't be called with a HQL query. You must pass it one city to delete.

Alternatively, you can use `session.createSQLQuery()` to create a delete statement. That allows you to delete many cities in one go. The drawback with this method is that you must delete the clients yourself **and** flush the cache (Hibernate makes no attempt to understand what your query might mean).

Comment: I was reffering to the information that session.delete() “Delete all objects returned by the query. Return the number of objects deleted.” Is it not true?

Comment: `Session#delete(String)` has been deprecated in Hibernate and moved to the classic API. Hibernate now offers some support for DML style operations (a la JPA).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I must have looked at some really old information.