# HQL doesn't delete the children (one-to-many) records, but ORM delete does

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, cascade, cascading-deletes

Consider i have a one-to-many relationship between two entities with **cascade="save-update,delete"** option for the collection. Deleting the parent object with hibernate's delete() method deletes the children but the same query in hql doesn't do that. I wonder why so? Here's my sample code.

**HQL Delete** (Doesn't delete the children)

```
Session session = getSession(); 
String queryStr = "delete from SuperParent where name='" + objName + "'";
Query query = session.createQuery(queryStr);
int noOfRows deleted = query.executeUpdate();
```

**Method Delete** (Deletes the children)

```
Session session = getSession();
String queryStr = "from SuperParent where name='" + objName + "'";
Query query = session.createQuery(queryStr);
List<SuperParent> symbols = query.list();
for (SuperParent symbol : symbols)
{
    session.delete(symbol);
}
```

The problem i see with the second code snippet is performance. It loads all the records into memory and then deletes it. We typically deal with huge amount of data and selecting all of them just for the purpose of deleting it is not a wise idea.

**EDIT**

I've read this post [Hibernate delete objects on cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715522/hibernate-delete-objects-on-cascade).

> A bulk delete does not cascade

But i'm wondering why so, and the solution suggested is "to delete the children at first and then delete the parent". I'm not very much convinced of the solution bcoz in a framework mostly the children are unknown who refers to the parent and wants to get deleted when the parent gets deleted. So in such cases should we mandatorily fetch and delete the records?

Below is a sample case in which i try to delete SuperParent

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<subclass discriminator-value="ParentTable" extends="mypackage.SuperParent" name="mypackage.ParentTable">

  <set name="childTable" table="ChildTable" cascade="save-update,delete" lazy="false" fetch="select">
              <key>
                  <column name="ID" not-null="true" />
              </key>
              <one-to-many class="com.webnms.m2m.model.ChildTable" />
        </set>

<join fetch="select" table="ParentTable">
<key on-delete="cascade">
<column name="ID"/>
</key>
<property column="ParentTableNAME" length="100" name="ParentTableName" type="string"/>
</join>
</subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Please let me know if you require more details on the same to throw some light on this. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate delete objects on cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715522/hibernate-delete-objects-on-cascade)

Comment: This duplicate basically tells you everything you experience

Comment: Can you share the mapping details? Also, your query `String queryStr = "delete from parentTable where name='" + objName + "'";` seems like a native query. If its a Native query then Hibernate can't perform cascading.

Comment: Nope, its a hibernate query. ParentTable is the name of the class and name is the property of the class. I'll update the mapping details.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Please see the edit.

Comment: Well, Hibernate doesn't support a bulk delete with cascading. You know have 2 options. 1: Write to Hibernate and suggest they support a bulk delete with cascade and wait for them to implement it. OR 2: You select all the entities you want to delete and delete one after another with the cascade

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, i'm more interested in knowing the reason why hibernate doesn't provide that. And FYKI i've already implemented the solution. I'm only looking a way out to make it better.

Comment: Unless you get an Hibernate developer on this question you wont get an definitive answer here. Write an email to them and ask for the reason. I would assume they were either too lazy or havent find a neat way to do it until now

Comment: I'll write a mail to hibernate and also wait here for someone who could have encountered the same and tried something similar.